# Iterating through elements get repeating result on Selenium on Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm having an issue that I'm struggling to understand. I have a HTML with a ul list with a bunch of li items, and within those li items they have elements that I would like to scrape using Selenium on Python. The website makeup is as follows

```
<ul id="results">
    <li>
        <div class="name">John</div>
        <div class="age">23</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="name">Bob</div>
        <div class="age">39</div>
    </li>
    ..... #more li
</ul>
```

So this seems like a pretty simple problem where we just save the li elements as a variable, and iterate through each list to save the information. The problem is that no matter what I do, my results always gives back the first list item over and over again. It will loop through the correct number of elements, but always refer back to the first one. So if I do the following

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="results"]/li""")
for result in results:
    name = result.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@class="name"]""").text
    print(name)
```

Now if there is 10 li elements in this particular case, the name "John" will just print out 10 times rather than updating based on the iterated list.

Comment: Try doing `find_element` *then* `find_elements`. (note plural) There's one results list and multiple names. Also double check your xpath.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your XPath for the 2nd search is incorrect. It must begin with `.`. Otherwise, it will start searching from the top. That's the reason why it always find the first item. See my example below.

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/li')
for result in results:
    name = result.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="name"]').text
    print(name)
```

Comment: That's the one! Thank you so much for your assistance. The missing dot was all the difference.

Comment: so to clarify the "." would start searching from the previous result or how does it work exactly?

Comment: @RyanN. Let says `.` is the current node that is processing. Your loop changes the variable `result` to the new `<li>`, if you don't begin the expression with `.`, the `//` in the XPath expression will always start searching from the top of the DOM.

Comment: gotcha. Once again thank you very much for the answer and explanation.